# Asian movie with Tomb-raider/Indiana-Jones/National-Treasure style boobytraps

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember the name of a movie I saw the ending of quite a few years ago which had people trying to get through multiple booby traps set along this ancient tomb/cave/temple setting. The movie looked like it was from the 90s/early 2000s, with an Asian cast and a female lead (at least in the parts I saw).

One of the traps I remember had arrows shooting out of these holes in wall. There were burning lamps in the front of holes to set fire to the arrows as they shot out.

Another one had the floor made up of tops of initially-hidden stone columns that collapse into a burning fire below with the actors (mainly the female lead) swinging on these ropes to save people.

I think there was also a lamp or a receptacle filled with oil, earlier in the movie, that they set fire to for opening one of the doors. That is what lit up the lamps above and the fire the columns above collapsed into (and possibly activated some of the other traps).

It might have been an Asian movie, but I saw it in English. Any help or guidance is really appreciated, I really want to see the complete movie.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is Chinese Zodiac with Jackie Chan. It had a female lead in it.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't catch an episode of [Relic Hunter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic_Hunter)?  The main lead is female (and vaguely asian in appearance) and she does get into some adventures in places where she would be surrounded by asians (as well as her british sidekick Nigel.)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about those two, they're both on my watchlist now! :D. I'm pretty sure I would have recognized Jackie Chan, I can go through Relic Hunter episodes, but I don't think that was the female lead in the movie I remember

Comment: Can you recall any specific elements that make you believe it was of the fantasy or science fiction genres?

Comment: Sounds like Kung For Yoga, not Chinese Zodiac. Swing ropes part was there, from what I remember it was very National Treasure like.  Oh and can't forget the Bollywood ending :)

Comment: @Rohit - I recently watched a movie with my wife that seems similar to what you are describing... by any chance would there have been a bit about candles? When they are trying to get stuff from the tombs they light candles and if the candles go out they abandon their plan believing there is bad luck? I also remember a coffin that was suspended in mid air that they were trying to break into. I can not remember the name of this movie, but I will keep searching...

Comment: @Xantec : Just the set up and some of the scenes from the tomb make me think it was fantasy, but I'd say it was closer to 'National Treasure'' than 'The Mummy'.

Comment: @Craqgerbil: Haha, as interesting as Kung Fu Yoga looks, it's too recent. Also, I don't remember seeing Jackie Chan in the movie.

Comment: @Odin1806, Thanks, that sounds similar to Teresa's answer, 'Mojin the lost legend'. It does look like an impressive movie. However, I didn't see anything familiar in the trailer and don't think it had the Candles bit you mentioned.